# In Ansible v2, which variable stores the ssh username?

Tags: ansible-2.x

In my playbooks, I SSH in as a non-root user, then use `become` to become `root`.

What is the Ansible variable name that stores the user that originally SSH'd into the box?

In Ansible < 2.0, I could use `{{ ansible_ssh_user }}` to access the username SSH'ing into the box.

Just tried with Ansible 2.0.2 and that returns `null`. I tried `ansible_user` as suggested by the [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-different-machines-needing-different-user-accounts-or-ports-to-log-in-with), but that also returns `null`. I also tried `ansible_user_id`, but that returns the result of `become`, not the original user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accesss this via `ansible_env.SUDO_USER`.

I tried a number of other variables, and almost all of them changed their values as soon as I used `become` on the remote node.

Answer (score 2):

`{{ ansible_user }}` does actually work fine for me with Ansible 2.5:

```
with_items:
  - root
  - "{{ ansible_user }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.ansible.com/archive/ansible/2.4/intro_inventory.html:

> Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user,
> ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user,
> ansible_host, and ansible_port. If you are using a version of Ansible
> prior to 2.0, you should continue using the older style variables
> (ansible_ssh_*). These shorter variables are ignored, without warning,
> in older versions of Ansible.

I was experiencing the same issue and using:

ansible_user after the host ip address as shown on the examples from the link (see below) worked for me under 2.14.6.

> [targets]
>
> ```
> localhost             ansible_connection=local  
> other1.example.com    ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_user=mpdehaan 
> other2.example.com    ansible_connection=ssh        ansible_user=mdehaan
> ```